# I don't understand why a equals 1 and b equals 0 in this program

Tags: c, printf, operators, post-increment

I don't understand why a equals 1 and b equals 0 at the end. They should be the same in my view. Thanks in advance.

```
#include "stdio.h"

int main()
{
    int a=0;
    int b=0;
    a++;
    printf("a=%d,b=%d",a,b++);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you know what "*post*" is standing for in "*post-increment*" ?

Comment: Do you understand what `b++` (i.e. *post* increment) does?

Comment: You've used the post-increment operator. So 'b' is evaluated before the increment happens. To achieve a == 1 && b == 1, use the pre-increment operator (++b).

Comment: Remove `a++;` and change `printf("a=%d,b=%d",a,b++);` to `printf("a=%d,b=%d",++a,b++);` and the result will be the same.

Answer (score 5):

Before this call:

```
printf("a=%d,b=%d",a,b++);
```

the variable a was already incremented by:

```
a++;
```

However in the pointed-to call of `printf`, the value of the post-increment expression `b++` is the value of the variable `b` before its increment. So 1 and 0 are output.

If you want to get the output 1 and 1, then use the pre-increment expression with the variable `b` like:

```
printf("a=%d,b=%d",a,++b);
```

From the C Standard (6.5.2.4 Postﬁx increment and decrement operators)

> 2 **The result of the postﬁx ++ operator is the value of the
>   operand**. As a side effect, the value of the operand object is
>   incremented (that is, the value 1 of the appropriate type is added to
>   it)...

Answer (score 2):

The operation `b++` sends `b` to `printf` before doing the increment. `a` is incremented before `printf` is called

Comment: Actually, the increment must be completed before `printf` is called, because C 2018 6.5.2.2 10 says there is a sequence point after the evaluations of the argument and before the call. So `b` is not “sent” to `printf` before the increment. Rather, the **value** of `b++` is the value of `b` before the increment, and it is this value, not `b`, that is passed to `printf`.

Comment: I was trying to keep it simple

Comment: Simply, the value of `b++` is the value of `b` before the increment, and `b` is incremented as a side effect.

Answer (score 2):

```
printf("a=%d,b=%d",a,b++);
```

Is logically equivalent to:

```
printf("a=%d,b=%d",a,b);
b++;
```

Comment: These are not equivalent; the increment to `b` must be performed before the function call occurs, per C 2018 6.5.2.2 10. If `b` were accessible to the called function (because it is defined with external linkage or its address has been made available in some way), the called function would see the incremented value of `b` with the former but not with the latter.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I said "logically" equivalent.

Comment: They are not logically equivalent; they have different observable behaviors.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I'll have to look into it.

Comment: After `#include <stdio.h>`, `int b=0; void foo(int x) { printf("%d %d\n", x, b); } int main(void) { foo(b++); }` prints “0 1”, but `int b=0; void foo(int x) { printf("%d %d\n", x, b); } int main(void) { foo(b); b++; }` prints “0 0”.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Thanks.